How do custom readers know about on-going posts?
If I set up my initial post on Blogger for custom readers and provide email addresses for invited readers, how can I ensure that they'll receive invitations to all my subsequent posts?

If you want Readers to follow your BLOG, you will need to add the Followers gadget.

Let readers follow your blog

Sign in to Blogger.
In the top left, click the Down arrow
Choose the blog to update.
In the left menu, click Layout.
Choose where you want to add the Followers gadget.
Click Add a Gadget.
In the window that opens, click More Gadgets. 8  Look for “Followers” and click Add .
Choose your settings.
Click Save.
To save the arrangement, in the bottom right, click Save .

  Source:   Manage blogs you follow

